# Android Studio 2.2 : I keep seeing "GPU tools not installed, install now"

Tags: android, gpu, android-studio-2.2

I've just downloaded the latest Android Studio 2.2 and I'm trying to use the GPU profiling tools.  On my LG G4 phone I've enabled up USB debugging & Profile GPU rendering (In adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo).

When using the Android Monitor (GPU) launching a GFX Trace gives me the message "GPU tools not installed, install now?".  If I go to the Configuration and enable 'Capture GPU Commands' it asks me the same.

I've checked in the SDK Manager and I have the Tools installed (3.1.0 & 1.3.0).

I've tried uninstalling, and reinstalling Android Studio.  I've tried a couple of different phones.  I've tried different combinations of settings on the phones.

I'm out of ideas.  Does anyone know what situation might mean GPU Tools are not recognised as installed?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem... Anyone?

Comment: same here. just did a fresh install of everything, and still i get the message "GPU Tools are not installed, install now"

Comment: Did you guys open a ticket at http://code.google.com/p/android/ ? It sounds like a bug

Answer (score 2):

I think I had this same problem a few weeks ago. I had two versions of the tools installed in the SDK Manager. I uninstalled both of those versions from there and then reinstalled the latest one (3.1.0 as of right now), then restarted Android Studio.

It might’ve been trying to use the older version instead of the new one and I’m pretty sure the old one isn’t compatible with the latest version of Studio.

Also if anyone is getting messages that your device needs to be rooted, you should go to `Run > Edit Configurations...`, then open the `Profiling` tab and enable `Capture GPU Commands`, then re-run your app from Studio. This loads the library at startup and you won’t need root. Uncheck the box again once you no longer need to debug.

I’ve also had issues opening the trace files and I’ve noticed that if I make shorter traces (about 5 seconds or shorter) my machine has a better chance of opening them without getting stuck. Sometimes closing the trace file and reopening it helps if it doesn’t load.

Answer (score 1):

*None of the answers above are of help to me. I try to integrate what I discovered.*

> My setup is: *Windows 10 / Android Studio 2.2.2*

**The GPU Monitor does not track anything and GPU trace not work.**

From...

- Run / Profiling / Capture GPU Commands or
- SDK Manager or
- from "Launch monitor GPU GFX trace mode"

Start the GPU Tools installation, but... install the OSX version (image) !!

[image]

Here I found an explanation, it's a bug: [code.google.com issues](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=224415)

**So I did the following:**

- I downloaded it manually from the correct link: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/gapid_2994895_windows.zip
- I installed the OSX version anyway.
- I copied from the zip file the only folder "windows" of "gapid_2994895_windows.zip\gapid\" in "C:\Users[user_name]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\gapid\3\"
- I relaunched Android Studio.

Now the situation is this:

- The GPU Monitor: not working.
- **The "Capture GPU Commands" if enabled starts tracking and it works.** But track everything from the beginning of the app (and saves many MB), and disconnects the Android Monitor, so you can not pause the GPU Monitor and start again when you need.
- If I press "cancel" to start tracking, the app will not start (I was hoping to launch the tracking when I need).

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version of ADB driver to your PC

you can find details here

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html